# Не работает javascript в webview на андроид 5 і 6!

Tags: java, android, webview

На андроид 5 і 6 не работает javascript:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

webView код:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        if (newProgress == 100) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        if (super.getDefaultVideoPoster() == null) {  // fix for android 6.0
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
        }
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(infoModel.getUrl());
```

Также пробовал:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

ето не рабоет!
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, нашли решение?